# How to put specific parameters as independent variables into csv-file in JMeter?

Tags: csv, jmeter

Let's say I need to use in JMeter csv file with intrusion of variables into it, not only as a set of values, something like following:

(string1:)  parameter11_value;${variable12};parameter13_value;${variable14};parameter15_value

(string2:)  parameter21_value;${variable22};parameter23_value;parameter24_value;${variable24};parameter25_value

(string3:)  parameter31_value;parameter32_value;${variable32};parameter33_value;parameter34_value;parameter35_value

etc. (no template in structure, only mix of constant part with variable part and ";" between them).

I.e. resulting string should be build both from constant values and external independent variables (external - relatively to csv file).

Are there a way to use in JMeter csv file not only values, but put/get/use dynamic parameters as variables from the another external file on the fly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, check out [__eval() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__eval)

Demo:

[image]

More information: [Here’s What to Do to Combine Multiple JMeter Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables)

Comment: Thank you, Dmitri. __eval()_function looks good enough for that.